# jQtouch Sort Buttons

Tags: javascript, iphone, css, jqtouch

I looked at the documentation of jqtouch but I could not figure out how to create iphone style sort button group like this attached picture.
http://img843.imageshack.us/img843/8669/captureov.png

Do you have any idea how to do this with jqtouch, is there any plug-in doing this for jqtouch?

Thank you for your response,
cas sakal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have to roll your own, with CSS (styling) and JavaScript (controlling the single selection).

I just quickly styled up a button group similar to the segmented control in iPhone, with help of [this article](http://css3wizardry.com/2010/08/31/iphone-style-tab-control-with-html-css-and-javascript-2/):

```
<style>
.buttonGroup
{
        display: -webkit-box;
        -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
        -webkit-box-pack:justify;
        -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}

.buttonGroup > li
{
        display: block;
        -webkit-box-flex: 1;
        border: solid 1px #9a9a99;
        border-left: none;
        -webkit-border-radius: 0px;
        text-align: center;
        background-image:
                -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom,
                        from(#fbfbfb),
                        to(#bdbdbd));
        color: #6b6b6b;
        font-size: 16px;
        padding: 10px;
}

.buttonGroup > li:first-child
{
        border-left: solid 1px #9a9a99;
        -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 10px;
        -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
}

.buttonGroup > li:last-child
{
        -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 10px;
        -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
}

.buttonGroup > li.selected
{
        background-image:
                -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom,
                        from(#2a55b1),
                        to(#6297f2));
        color: #fff;
        border-color: #193a7f;
}
</style>

<ul class="buttonGroup">
  <li class="selected">button</li>
  <li>button</li>
  <li>button</li>
</ul>
```